# Root Bound Cucumber Transplants

Tags: transplanting

I just purchased cucumber seedlings that I had called the greenhouse ahead about. When I got there I realized that the cell pack of cucumbers were extremely root bound. Knowing that cucumbers are sensitive to their roots being touched does anyone have any advice for when I go to transplant them? If I wouldn't have already committed to buying them I certainly wouldn't have bothered. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience cucumbers are pretty forgiving.  Plant them out as soon as possible in good garden soil with some compost worked in.  Water them in well and keep them watered if there isn't enough rain.

Normally when planting out cucumber starts I put them in a small well and make sure that the top of the soil plug they are growing in is covered by a few cm of your garden soil to help hold in the moisture.

I'm not sure of your location and it does vary by variety of cucumber how long they may grow and produce (and also pollination), but we manage to keep our cucumber plants growing through the entire summer and up until the days start getting frosty (or we get tired of eating them and pull out the plants).